# How to split partitions into subpartitions? Unique hash function generator?

Tags: hash, apache-kafka, partitioning, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka topic with `N` partitions. The record key is a cookie. Records are distributed across partitions with the formula `hash(key) % N`.

I want to process records form partitions in a parallel way. Let's say that each partition has `M` workers assigned to do the processing. Additional requirement is that the same cookie is processed by a single worker thread (to keep events order).

I don't know the `hash` function used for partitioning records. Computing `my_hash(key) % M` may not work properly if I use `my_hash == hash` and `gcd(N, M) > 1` (particularly when `N = M`).

Since I know `partitionId` for all records, my initial idea was to compute `my_hash(key + "." + partitionId) % M` but I am wondering whether this kind of bucketing is good enough. There is a chance that `hash(key) == h1(key + "." + (h2(key) % N)) == my_hash(key + "." + partitionId)`.

I think I should generate a unique hash function. Do you know such generators?

**EDIT**

Example:

```
Partition1: (cookie1, ...), (cookie1, ...), (cookie3, ...)
Partition2: (cookie2, ...), (cookie2, ...), (cookie4, ...)
```

I want to have 2 threads (`N = M`) processing each partition. I don't know `hash` function, so it can happen that I will choose `my_hash == hash`.

Then I will get:

```
Partition1_Subpartition1: (cookie1, ...), (cookie1, ...), (cookie3, ...)
Partition1_Subpartition2: <always_empty>
Partition2_Subpartition1: <always_empty>
Partition2_Subpartition2: (cookie2, ...), (cookie2, ...), (cookie4, ...)
```

Instead better possible split, e.g.:

```
Partition1_Subpartition1: (cookie3, ...)
Partition1_Subpartition2: (cookie1, ...), (cookie1, ...)
Partition2_Subpartition1: (cookie4, ...)
Partition2_Subpartition2: (cookie2, ...), (cookie2, ...)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Kafka will put all records with the same key in the same partition. If you have multiple consumers in the same consumer group, each consumer is guaranteed to receive records from one (or more, if you have more partitions than consumers) partition.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Let's say that we want to have higher parallelism than N Kafka partitions provide. For each partition I want to have M subpartitions with a single cookie not split between different subpartitions.

Comment: Doesn't work like that. Partitions are your unit of parallelism.

Comment: You can use a thread pool, so when a consumer consumes K ConsumerRecords, you could process each record in a different thread. That is the kind of extra parallelism you can achieve (just shorten processing time after each poll cycle). Now what logic you use to spread the consumer records between the different threads - that's totally up to you

Comment: @RobinMoffatt This question has to do more with general hashing and partitioning that with Kafka. Why did you remove some tags? I put Kafka in the desc because I use Kafka, but the problem comes down to dividing partitions into subpartitions. I am reverting your edit of tags.

Comment: @LiorChaga The question is about distributing records across threads evenly, but with the requirement that records with the same cookie are not split.

Comment: @tomek no problem. Suppose you get the key for each consumer record, now you can bucket the different consumer records according to cookie. and then each bucket would be processed by different threads. Once consumer got the messages, this is no longer a kafka question - this is just a worker threadpool question and how you assign work to your workers.

Comment: I've updated the description to make it more clear what I need to achieve and what is my problem with hashing functions

Answer (score 0):

A Kafka consumer needs to run in its own separate thread. It's not possible(or advised) to share a thread among multiple consumers. So, if you have `M` threads, that implies you have `M` consumers. Now, let's come to your requirement:

> I want to read the topic in a parallel way with M threads so that all
>   records with the same cookie are read by a single thread.

This statement itself looks a bit foggy to me. Because the default hash function ensures that same cookie will always come to the same partition, so your requirement is anyway going to be satisfied.

> I want to have 2 threads (N = M) processing each partition.

Do you mean, that you want each partition being processed by two consumer threads? That's not possible, unless they are in different consumer-groups, which I think isn't what you want.

Now, are you trying to redirect a particular key (cookie) to different partitions, based on some function (maybe timestamp, or whatever), and if you know, that it can go to any of the partitions in the set (p1, p2, ... pn) then you want a single consumer to consume all these n partitions? Then what would you be gaining compared to the situation if all occurrences of the same cookie came to the same partition? Because in the end it's the same Kafka consumer thread consuming it. And, along the same line, I think if your Kafka consumer thread delegates the processing job to a threadpool (which you might be talking about), then also it doesn't matter whether you consume same key from same partition or a set of different partitions, the threadpool size will determine how much parallelism you'll achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've updated the description to make it more clear what I need to achieve and what is my problem with hashing functions